# how to convert string to Datein android(java)

Tags: android, string, date, calendar

In my android app I have get a string from webservice like this-

```
 2012-10-17 22:54:00          or        2012-10-17 08:48:00
```

I want to convert this string into following string-

```
2012-10-17 10:54:00 PM        or        2012-10-17 08:48:00 AM
```

How to do that in android.I have done following but could not get such result.
Also date class methods like gethours(),getminutes() are depricated.How to do that?

WHat I have done-

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(publishtime);
            dateFormat.setLenient(true);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        Log.i("", "CREATE Date"+convertedDate);//the resut of log is - CREATE DateMon Jan 16 00:10:00 GMT+05:30 2012


        Log.i("", "HOURS:"+hour);
        if(hour>=12)
            publishtime=publishtime+" PM";
        else
            publishtime=publishtime+" AM";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are not setting right pattern for parsing the date, it should be

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

To get converted string use

```
SimpleDateFormat convertedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
convertedFormat.format(convertedDate);
```

Comment: yes, sometimes people answer while other people still write their answers, so after all submit you get several very similar answers :)
First deserves accept, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dfTime_a= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a");
SimpleDateFormat dfTime= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss");

public String formatTime(String str)
{
    java.util.Date d = null;

    try {
        d = dfTime.parse(str);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    str = dfTime_a.format(d);
    return str;
}
```

**Checking**

formatTime("2012-10-17 22:54:00") which gives op as 2012-10-17 10:54:00 pm

Comment: I have found one issue in this answer.  Time between 12 to 13 (i.e 12 to 1) shows-->  12:12:00 AM  instead of 12:12:00 PM

Comment: Just changing Simpledateformat parameter solve this prob.SimpleDateFormat dfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");SimpleDateFormat dfTime_a = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");

Comment: can u tell me what should be the date format for this       Wed, 24 Oct 2012 10:58:06   to convert into  24/11/2012 10:58

Comment: Try using EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss for your date Wed, 24 Oct 2012 10:58:06

Comment: I have done this with using following format - EEE, d MMM yy hh:mm:ss and your format is also write thanks for ans..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String publishTime="2012-10-17 22:54:00";
    SimpleDateFormat inputTime= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat outputTime= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd KK:mm:ss a");
    Date date=inputTime.parse(publishTime);
    publishTime = outputTime.format(d);
    Log.i("", "CREATE Time"+publishTime);
```

Comment: can u tell me what should be the date format for this       Wed, 24 Oct 2012 10:58:06   to convert into  24/11/2012 10:58